# How to add constraint to entity framework model builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I am trying to add the following constraint in entity framework model builder,

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] ADD  CONSTRAINT [uc_Portfolio_idx1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have tried `entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Id).HasName("uc_Portfolio_idx1");`but didn't work
If I add it as an index, it adds it as index not as constraint

Is there a way of creating that in model builder? I want to avoid adding it to migration script